# Irreducibility of $p(x)$ implies that of $p(x+c)$ only when taken over a field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

$R$  is  a  ring and  $R[x]$  is  the  polynomial  ring  over  $R$ . $c$  is  any  fixed  element  of  $R$ . Then  the  map  $f(x)\mapsto f(x+c)$  is  an  isomorphism from $R[x]$  to  itself. Now  with  the  assumption  that  $R$  is  a  field  it  is  written  that  $p(x)$  is  irreducible  in  $R[x]$  iff  $p(x+c)$  is  irreducible  in  $R[x]$.

Now  here  is  my  question:  Why  do  we  need  the  assumption  that  $R$  is  a field $?$ Since  $p(x)\mapsto p(x+c)$  is  already  an  isomorphism (irrespective  of  whether  $R$  is a field  or  not)  then  does  not irreducibility  of  one  automatically  imply  irreducibility  of  the  other $?$  What  am  I  missing  here?

Comment: Why do you think you're missing anything? The lemma is usually proved and used in settings where we're exploring polynomial rings over a field, so that's how the lemma gets stated up front, even though as you note it is more general.

Comment: The notion of *irreducible element* is useful mainly in UFDs. A polynomial ring $R[x]$  is a UFD if and only if $R$ is a UFD — in particular if $R$  is a field.

Comment: @anon: It's  a  problem  given  to  solve. First  it  mentions  $R$  to  be  any  arbitrary  ring  and  to  prove  the  isomorphism $f(x)\mapsto f(x+c)$ on  $R[x]$ . After  that  it  asks  to  prove  the  irreducibility  part  with  the  clause "when  $R$  is  a  field" . That  is  where  my  confusion  is.